# Restructure Voronoi data to custom graph without brute force

Tags: c#

I was asking about a very specific method (`MakeCorner`) in another question but we reached to conclusion that changing that single method is not giving the speedup Im hoping for, therefore it requires restructuring on higher level.

---

Im restructuring the data from [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) to custom graph structure for my own needs. I made this code as obvious and short as possible (removed validation *etc*).

Voronoi output Im working with is rather standard across all the libraries and languages, most useful ones being:

- list of sites coordinates - `Vector2` in this case
- edges - each edge has 2 endpoints (`Vector2`) and 2 sites (`Vector2`) on both sides

---

Main theme of this code is for each component (site, edge, corner) to directly hold all the data or rather pointers to all the surrounding components, example:

Site knows about:

- all the surrounding corners that form the cell around the site
- all the surrounding edges that form the cell around the site
- all the neighbor sites

**Question:** how to avoid using `MakeCorner` method? How to fuse all the edges endpoints that "meet" to single corner without spending 98-99% of total time to it? 10,000 points, ~2500ms.

```cs
public class ExampleClass {
    List<Site> sites;
    List<Edge> edges;
    List<Corner> corners;

    void BuildGraph(Voronoi voronoiData) {
        sites = new List<Site>();
        edges = new List<Edge>();
        corners = new List<Corner>();

        List<Vector2> siteCoords = voronoiData.SiteCoords();
        List<VEdge> voronoiEdges = voronoiData.edges;

        // for fast site lookup by Vector2
        Dictionary<Vector2, Site> sitesByV2 = new Dictionary<Vector2, Site>(); 


        // populate sites
        for (int i = 0; i < siteCoords.Count; i++) {
            Site site = new Site(siteCoords[i]);
            sites.Add(site);
            sitesByV2.Add(siteCoords[i], site);
        }

        // populate edges, corners and relationships between all 3 (site, edge, corner)
        for (int i = 0; i < voronoiEdges.Count; i++) {
            // both edge endpoints
            Vector2 leftEnd = voronoiEdges[i].leftEnd;
            Vector2 rightEnd = voronoiEdges[i].rightEnd;
            // sites on both sides of edge
            Vector2 leftSite = voronoiEdges[i].leftSite;
            Vector2 rightSite = voronoiEdges[i].rightSite;

            Edge edge = new Edge();
            edges.Add(edge);

            // corners to edges (reuse corner if one edge already created it)
            edge.leftEnd = MakeCorner(leftEnd); // MakeCorner is the slow part!
            edge.rightEnd = MakeCorner(rightEnd); // 98-99% of total time

            // sites to edges
            edge.leftSite = sitesByV2[leftSite];
            edge.rightSite = sitesByV2[rightSite];

            // edge to sites
            edge.leftSite.edges.Add(edge);
            edge.rightSite.edges.Add(edge);

            // edge to corners
            edge.leftEnd.protrudes.Add(edge);
            edge.rightEnd.protrudes.Add(edge);

            // sites to sites (neighbor sites)
            AddToList(edge.leftSite.neighbors, edge.rightSite);
            AddToList(edge.rightSite.neighbors, edge.leftSite);

            // corners to corners
            AddToList(edge.leftEnd.adjecent, edge.rightEnd);
            AddToList(edge.rightEnd.adjecent, edge.leftEnd);

            // corners to sites
            AddToList(edge.leftSite.corners, edge.leftEnd);
            AddToList(edge.leftSite.corners, edge.rightEnd);

            AddToList(edge.rightSite.corners, edge.leftEnd);
            AddToList(edge.rightSite.corners, edge.rightEnd);

            // sites to corners
            AddToList(edge.leftEnd.touches, edge.leftSite);
            AddToList(edge.leftEnd.touches, edge.rightSite);

            AddToList(edge.rightEnd.touches, edge.leftSite);
            AddToList(edge.rightEnd.touches, edge.rightSite);
        }
    }

    void AddToList(List<T> v, T x) {
        if (x != null && v.IndexOf(x) < 0) v.Add(x);
    }

    // dictionary bucketed by x coordinate for faster lookup
    Dictionary<int, List<Corner>> lookup = new Dictionary<int, List<Corner>>();

    Corner MakeCorner(Vector2 point) {
        int bucket = (int)point.x;

        for (int i = bucket - 1; i <= (int)point.x + 1; i++) {
            if (lookup.ContainsKey(i)) {
                for (int j = 0; j < lookup[i].Count; j++) {
                    float dx = point.x - lookup[i][j].coords.x;
                    float dy = point.y - lookup[i][j].coords.y;
                    if (dx * dx + dy * dy < 0.000001f) {
                        return lookup[i][j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Corner corner = new Corner(point);
        corners.Add(corner);
        if (!lookup.ContainsKey(bucket)) lookup[bucket] = new List<Corner>();
        lookup[bucket].Add(corner);
        return corner;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still an X/Y problem. *why* do you need the data in this form? What are you trying to accomplish with your voronoi diagram?

Comment: In my experience, a voronoi diagram is just a function that takes you from any point in the space to its nearest neighbor. The "edges", "corners" etc. are just inflection points of this function. You can create the edges by computing the dual of the voroni diagram (the delauny triangulation), then computing the dual of that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85275/how-do-i-derive-a-voronoi-diagram-given-its-point-set-and-its-delaunay-triangula

Comment: @mklingen Again, Im not using Voronoi diagram just for in-memory calculations (e.g nearest neighbors), I don't need Delaunay triangulation (which is essentially just lines between sites). Im using it for visualization and each component (site, edge, corner) has custom logic and state that needs to persist for the lifespan of game session and to be able to serialize this data to file. Im using some of this state to build meshes in 3D space (corners are vertices, cells form meshes) and other state for game logic. It's necessary to have all 3 components as separate classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Main theme of this code is for each component (site, edge, corner) to directly hold all the data or rather pointers to all the surrounding components

It's very easy to go from the object graph representation to "list of adjacent Vector2" and relatively hard (most code, much slower, etc) to go from "list of adjacent Vector2" to the object graph.

The best solution is to change the `Voronoi` class that is calculating the graph to return a `VoronoiEdge` class that has pointers to 2 VoronoiSites and 2 VoronoiCorners. Since while calculating the graph, it has access to adjacency information, this is going to be much faster and reliable than any kind of hack we code to address the current API design.

---

The other solution to your stated problem is to find a more performant data structure to find "nearby corners", since it seems you cannot rely on all edges having precisely the same floating point value for their endpoint. You could use a Dictionary that stores both X and Y values to help with lookup.

Alternatively, the simplest change would be to set the width of each "column" in your dictionary be around the size of your delta (0.000001) instead of 1, for better performance. You will have to check 2 columns to avoid missing out on nearby points straddling a boundary though.